Identifying the 3 Euler angles of rotation from 2 perspective images of a rectangle
I've worked on this problem for 3 days and I've decided to reach out for help. I have 2 images of the same rectangle (see figures). In the first image I have a 2D rectangle, and I know its height and width. In the second image I have the same rectangle but its rotated and I know its corner's 2D points.
What I need to do is determine the angle which it was rotated.
I am hoping that someone can give me an equation(s) that will get me the angles from the given information.

EDIT: As the figure above shows, the rectangle plane is initially parallel to the $xy$ plane of the camera.  Then the rectangle is rotated such that its perspective image created by the camera is shown on the right of the above figure.  The four vertices of this quadrilateral are known.  Using this information, I want to determine the relative rotation (with respect to the initial position/orientation).  That is, I want to determine the matrix $R$ relating the (world) positions of the two rectangles.


I'm not sure, but I bet projective-geometry tag shouldn't be applied here. The concept of angle you refer to isn't clear which angle it is. Is it the Euler angles? It might help to consider a rod (say a single side of your rectangles) and consider that rod being rotated in the sense you think (say the new position of side after rotation). Can you calculate the angle? Since a rectangle is rigid, rotating two sides such that they align with your desired form might help.

All 3 angles. Angles around the X, Y and Z

Not the best way perhaps, but to give you help (I don't think anyone would bother too much to give you the analytic result for arbitrary rectangles) . The order of rotations must be specified. Supposing it is known that you rotate along $x$ first and finally along $z$ axis, call the rotation angles $\alpha ,\beta, \gamma$. Each rotation is specified by rotation matrices $R_x(\alpha),\dots, R_z(\gamma)$. Now apply them to your vertices. You will get final vertex $= R_zR_yR_x$ initial vertex. Now solve for $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ since you know the initial and finals.

Let abcd be the original rectangle. Make an half turn about $\frac{d+D}2$. Let image of $c$ be $C_1.$ Make a rotation with center $D$ which sends $c_1$ to $C$. Finally, make a rotation about the axis $CD$ which overlaps the last image.

The projective transformation that generally maps a rectangle to four points cannot always be fully described by a rotation matrix (e.g. a shear operation in the x direction). However, there are multiple methods to find the "best" rotation matrix for a transformation, most of which yield more than one equivalent solution. We thus typically require some level of prior knowledge to disambiguate. Here are three methods that I've used before:
Method 1: Vanishing Points
For two lines parallel in 3D space, their intersection in projective 2D space is a vanishing point. This point gives the direction of those parallel lines in the coordinate frame of your camera. For example, if lines AB and CD correspond to the lines originally parallel to x-axis before transformation, the projective intersection of those lines would give the x-axis in the camera's frame. This intersection is computed by the cross product between the two lines. How do we get the two lines in the first place? This is also given by the cross product between points! So, your coordinate axes are simply:
$$(A \times B) \times (C \times D) = \hat{x}_{camera}$$
$$(A \times D) \times (B \times C) = \hat{y}_{camera}$$
Note that we are dealing with projective points, so each point would be given as $\begin{bmatrix}x & y & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ where x and y are the image coordinates. We then normalize $\hat{x}_{camera}$ and $\hat{y}_{camera}$ to get their unit vectors. Then, the rotation matrix is just given by:
$$R = \begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}_{camera} & \hat{y}_{camera} & \hat{x}_{camera} \times \hat{y}_{camera}\end{bmatrix}$$
Note $\hat{x}_{camera} \times \hat{y}_{camera}$ must be normalized as well. There are two caveats. Firstly, the cross product is antisymmetric, so the order of cross product can potentially negate $\hat{x}_{camera}$ and/or $\hat{y}_{camera}$. In many situations, you have prior information about the camera orientation (e.g. y component of y-axis is >0), so it would be easy to check the resulting vector and negate it.
The second caveat is that if the transformation of the points is not given perfectly as a rotation (e.g. due to noise), $\hat{x}_{camera}$ and $\hat{y}_{camera}$ may not be orthogonal. As such, we can "correct" them by finding the nearest rotation matrix. This is akin to solving Wahba's Problem on $\hat{x}_{camera}$ and $\hat{y}_{camera}$ whose solution is given by $R = UMV^T$ where $U$ and $V^T$ come from the SVD of the original estimate of $R$, and $M=diag(1, 1, det(U)*det(V))$ (there are also faster solutions for just two points, e.g. this paper$^1$).
Method 2: Homography
The general projective linear transformation mapping 4 points is in fact a homography. Homographies are uniquely defined up to scale by 4 points and can be estimated easily with OpenCV for example. As mentioned before, the homography may not be a rotation matrix, so we once again apply Wahba's problem to find the nearest rotation $R = UMV^T$ with $M$ same as before and $U$ and $V^T$ coming from the SVD of the homograpy matrix. This gives a single solution, but we would have to manually recover any other equivalent solutions by 180 degree rotations if the recovered solution is unsatisfactory.
Method 3: Direct Formula
Finally, assuming the transformation of the four points is truly from a rotation, there are explicit formulas for uncovering the Euler angles of the rotation. The formulas are a bit tedious, so I will refer you to the original paper$^2$ for them. There are always two feasible solutions in this approach, so we would once again need prior information to disambiguate them.
Good luck!
$^1$Markley, Landis. (2002). Fast Quaternion Attitude Estimation from Two Vector Measurements. Journal of Guidance Control and Dynamics - J GUID CONTROL DYNAM. 25. 411-414. 10.2514/2.4897.
$^2$Robert M. Haralick, Determining camera parameters from the perspective projection of a rectangle, Pattern Recognition, Volume 22, Issue 3, 1989, Pages 225-230, ISSN 0031-3203, https://doi.org/10.1016/0031-3203(89)90071-X.
